# Did Darth Maul EVER talk?

Tags: star-wars, darth-maul

I watched all nine *Star Wars* movies, but I don't know if in any other movie or series Darth Maul talks. I never heard him, but I think I know his voice. It could be a false memory, but I want to be certain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He talks to Darth Sidious a couple of times in *The Phantom Menace*.

> **<sub><sup>"Tatooine is sparsely populated. If the trace was correct, I will find them quickly, Master"</sup></sub>**
> **<sub><sup>"At last we will reveal ourselves to the Jedi. At last we will have our revenge"</sup></sub>**

and

> <sub><sup>**"Yes, my master"**</sup></sub>

---

You may also be mis-remembering him speak from *Solo: A Star Wars Story*

> 

or one of his scenes from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*

> 

or one of his scenes from *Star Wars: Rebels*

> 

or his appearance in Lego Star Wars

> 

Comment: He also talks when he shows up at the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Adventure*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44i60VyUng8

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - Indeed. That's already in my answer though